# How to deserialize a xml string along with NCR unescaping?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, xml-deserialization

I have a serialized XML string which I want to convert into XML object. But his string contains few Numeric character reference like `&amp;#xA5;`. I used [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for deserialization but it doesn't unescape these characters.

And if I unescape using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), the `&amp;` in query parameters of URLs present in string also gets unescaped that invalidates the URL for XML parser. For example,
`https://testURL.com?param1=a&amp;param2=b` gets converted to `https://testURL.com?param1=a&param2=b` and now `&param2` is an invalid character for XML parser.

One naive way would be to replace all `&amp;#` with `&#` before sending to simplexml_load_string but that might break few things. Please let me know the better way of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you have is content that has been double-escaped; you need to unpick the order it was processed in, and reverse those steps, **in reverse order** to get back the original text.

For instance, if the XML you have looks like this:

```
<thing url="https://testURL.com?param1=a&amp;param2=b" description="blah &amp;#xA5; blah" />
```

Then its likely that the original transforms were:

1. Escape description manually, changing `¥` to `&#xA5;`; leave URL unchanged
2. Add `url` and `description` as XML attributes, escaping `&` to `&amp;`

So to reverse, you need to:

1. Reverse step 2: Extract `url` and `description` attributes (using SimpleXML)
2. Reverse step 1: Unescape the `description` value, but leave the `url` value unchanged

Giving you:

```
// Step 1; reverses the original step 2
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$url = (string)$xml['url'];
$description = (string)$xml['description'];

// Step 2; reverses the original step 1
$description = html_entity_decode( $description );
```