# XML Numeric Character References in Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize an XML response from an external service containing more than 100.000 rows, but I have a problem unescapeing numeric character references in various places. Since the DOM is complex, I need to have a global solution that applies to the whole document, and not it's specific elements. I have the following situations:

```
 <text>First &amp;#38; Second</text>
```

I use the following XmlSerializer implementation:

```
public T DeserializeXmlReader<T>(string path) where T : class
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

After deserialization, I will get the following result: "First &#38 Second", instead of "First & Second". I am not sure if there is an additional step I need to undertake to get the "&" deserialized correctly?

Note: After doing some research, I believe the problem might be similar to this one, but I'm not sure if it's applicable since this concerns php: [How to deserialize a xml string along with NCR unescaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413165/how-to-deserialize-a-xml-string-along-with-ncr-unescaping)

Comment: You are getting exactly the correct results.  Better check documentation to find out what the #38 actually means.  The code that produced the xml may have an error.

Comment: Although it might be time consuming to do this in the future, I found that,after deserializing, I can use WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source) on a single string property to decode any special entities inside that string to regular text, meaning it will become just "&" after decoding.

Comment: I just tried it and still seeing the #38.

Comment: I believe that double conversion of the symbol `&` occurred incorrectly when generating xml. First it was converted to decimal code `&#38;`, and then this value was converted to `&amp;#38;`. Find out why this happens when generating xml.